# How can i make sure nginx in django is working?

Tags: django, error-handling, nginx, http-status-code-404

I am using nginx in django , i want to include custom HTTP error handlers(like handler404,500..). So i want make sure the nginx is working and my custome error handlers are working. I want one method to check it .
code for that custome error pages in my nginx conf file is shown below:

```
error_page 404 /404.html;
   location = /404.html {
       root  html;
       internal;
   }
error_page 403 /403.html;
   location = /403.html {
       root  html;
       allow all;
   }
error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
   location = /50x.html {
       root  html;
       allow all;
   }
```

Anyone got idea to make sure my nginx is working in localhost?

Comment: Why are you handling these "views" via nginx instead of [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views)?

Comment: To see if nginx is running: `ps aux | grep "nginx"`

Comment: @HeddevanderHeide van der Heide , I am using nginx as a web server .It handles everything. I have tried your command ,i got something like:              user  10013  0.0  0.1  50684  4808 pts/1    T    16:26   0:00 vim nginx
user  16240  0.0  0.0  13632   932 pts/5    S+   20:40   0:00 grep nginx
That means it is working ,right?

Comment: seems it's not, it says you're editing the config file (vim) and the last report is for your grep search.

Comment: It may be some configuration problem, the server name i have given is 127.0.0.1:8001 because it's running in localhost. So is it a problem?

Comment: Hedde van der Heide , now nginx is working and i have added "samp" conf file to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled ,but still localhost showing the default page ? do i have to make more moidification?